# Why am I getting a CSRF token mismatch with Laravel and Sanctum?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have a Laravel backend and react frontend where I use sanctum for SPA authentication and Axios to make my requests. I am using localhost with my backend on http://localhost:8000 and frontend on http://localhost:3000.

Here is my frontend code:

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8000`,
    withCredentials: true,
});    

let config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
}

export async function login(credentials: LoginCredentials) {

    return apiClient.get('sanctum/csrf-cookie', config).then(response => {
        apiClient.post('/api/v1/login', JSON.stringify(credentials));
    });
}
```

my api middleware class looks like this

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            'throttle:api',
        ],
```

These are my sanctum configurations;

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,localhost:3000/api/v1/login,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),

SESSION_DOMAIN=http://localhost:3000
```

And finally my cors middleware

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

I am pretty sure i am missing something minor. Any help would me appreciated

Comment: could you add `Accept` with `application/json` in headers.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the `SESSION_DOMAIN` for `localhost:3000` as it's already included as the default. Also, you should only need to add the domain i.e. don't include the `http://` bit. What response/status (network tab) are you getting back from your `login` request?

Comment: @Faesal using accept with application json does not change anything.

Comment: @Rwd the response status I get is a token mismatch exception

Comment: remove `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` from my api middlewares

Answer (score 7):

Set this in you backend env

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

Comment: I have the same issue and this solves it seamlessly

Comment: please add some description about why this works. Thank you.

Comment: 'SESSION_DOMAIN' is an environment variable that establishes which domains the cookie is available to. This value is used in the config/session.php file.

'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS' should also be in the .env file, to specify the domains that will receive stateful API authentication cookies (backend and frontend).

Answer (score -2):

The reason you got this problem is that you need to hit the csrf-cookie
Before you can login or register (You will have the same problem when you are sending a post but not logged in.)

`await this.$axios({ url: "/v1/sanctum/csrf-cookie" });`

This is also mentioned in the docs
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#csrf-protection

You can find the csrf-cookie route using `php artisan route:list`

You can also set your own csrf-cookie route in config/santrum
`'prefix' => 'api/v1/sanctum'`

Answer (score -3):

because you are using post method .you have two way to fix this problem:

1- use get method

2- go to this path

```
app/http/middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

and set your path inside

```
protected $except = []
```

for exception csrf token.

Comment: I am making a login request so it's going to be a post request.

Comment: ok. i know. you just use above instruction for fix it. trust me

Comment: Adding an exception is not a fix but bypassing the whole point of csrf